# How to get old toolchain for Linux

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, intel, toolchain, linux-toolchain

We have a project that was working fine in Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2. Since GCC version is getting updated periodically, we wanted to have our project to be independent of GCC upgrade in local system. Hence we wanted to keep GCC toolchain (binaries and libraries) in our project rather than standard location in the machine. ldd of our binaries generated out of our project should depend on the libraries in my our project not from the gcc libraries available in local system (because it might change at any time).

How do I do that? Where I shall get specific GCC toolchain for intel 64 bit (C & C++ compilers) ?

Current GCC Version: gcc-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64

Comment: You write a check to FSF and they send you a magnetic tape with the sources.

Comment: We are already facing some problem, as the system is upgraded to next gcc version. Do you feel that it may not be the fair idea to have specific compiler local to the project?

Comment: There are two separate, very different questions here. (1) Should we upgrade gcc (and/or everything else)? (2) How technically can we stay on the old version of gcc while upgrading everything else?

Comment: Yes you are right. I need answer to second question. System is getting upgraded periodically. We will have project in various machines which will have different version of libraries (Ex: Gcc). Hence we wanted to keep all dependency libraries local to the project. Please let me know your suggestion what can be done here.

Comment: What we do: install gcc from sources (all major releases from 4.4 and up, separately) on a network drive and mount it on all machined that need a compiler.

Comment: Is it also applicable for libraries like openssl, sqllite and etc? Can  I do the same thing?

Comment: Yes, pretty much to everything (and we do it with lots of other tools too). It is important to build everything against the lowest possible libc version (use the oldest distro version you can, or maintain your own build of libc too). Now the question is why upgrade at all if you keep old versions of all the important libs...